# Merging CSV Files into a XLSX with Tabs

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, merge

I currently have 5  Registry CSV files which are created during a PowerShell script:

- HKCC
- HKCR
- HKCU
- HKLM
- HKU

I need these CSV files to open at the end of the script however would like if all of them were contained within one XLSX file with 5 different headings

Is there a way to combine the files through PowerShell?

I understand how to get the data of the CSV files but don't understand how to merge them or convert. Some of the variables I believe which may be helpful.

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format "d.MMM.yyyy"
$DIR = $WPFlistview.Selecteditem.Ransomware
$path = "F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\*"
$csvs = Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.csv
$output = "F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\Results.Xlsx"
```

Paths to the CSV files if needed:

```
F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\HKCR.CSV
F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\HKCU.CSV
F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\HKLM.CSV
F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\HKU.CSV
F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\HKCC.CSV
```

This is what I have tried prior. However, it completly scrambles my data into the wrong lines and cells:

```
function MergeCSV {
  $Date = Get-Date -Format "d.MMM.yyyy"
  $DIR = $WPFlistview.Selecteditem.Ransomware
  $path = "F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\*"
  $csvs = Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.csv
  $y = $csvs.Count
  Write-Host "Detected the following CSV files: ($y)"
  foreach ($csv in $csvs) {
    Write-Host " "$csv.Name
  }
  $outputfilename = "Final Registry Results"
  Write-Host Creating: $outputfilename
  $excelapp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
  $excelapp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = $csvs.Count
  $xlsx = $excelapp.Workbooks.Add()
  $sheet = 1
  foreach ($csv in $csvs) {
    $row = 1
    $column = 1
    $worksheet = $xlsx.Worksheets.Item($sheet)
    $worksheet.Name = $csv.Name
    $file = (Get-Content $csv)
    foreach ($line in $file) {
      $linecontents = $line -split ',(?!\s*\w+")'
      foreach ($cell in $linecontents) {
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $cell
        $column++
      }
      $column = 1
      $row++
    }
    $sheet++
  }
  $output = "F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\Results.Xlsx"
  $xlsx.SaveAs($output)
  $excelapp.Quit()
}
```

How the CSV looks
https://gyazo.com/177c7c3bb21ddf06d0ebacbb7f4d537b

How the XLSX looks
https://gyazo.com/cd5fb48d61f93aac5ec3034d81811094

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! While we are excited to see new users and help them with their coding/scripting problems, we are not a code writing service. Please show what you have tried in order to accomplish this yourself, and let us know what trouble you encountered when you tried it. I'm sure we can help you figure out where things went wrong once we see what you tried, and offer corrections, or possibly a better way to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Thanks, Done this now to provide better understanding

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! I'll get an answer based on what you have there together for you shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`ImportExcel` by Doug Finke](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) And then replace your `Export-CSV` in the original script with `Export-Excel -WorksheetName`

```
Install-Module ImportExcel
Export-Excel "F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\Results.xlsx" -worksheetname "HKCR"
Export-Excel "F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\Results.xlsx" -worksheetname "HKCU"
```

Answer (score 3):

So, using the Excel.Application ComObject still, what I would suggest is loading each CSV as a CSV, not using `Get-Content` like you are. Then use the `ConvertTo-CSV` cmdlet, specifying to use tab as the delimiter, and copy that to the clipboard. Then just paste into Excel, and it will paste in fairly nicely. You may want to adjust column size, but the data will show up just as you would expect it to. I would also use a `For` loop instead of a `ForEach` loop, since Excel plays nice with numbers for the tabs (though it is 1 based instead of PowerShell's 0 base). Here's what I would end up with after making those modifications:

```
function MergeCSV {
  $Date = Get-Date -Format "d.MMM.yyyy"
  $DIR = $WPFlistview.Selecteditem.Ransomware
  $path = "F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\*"
  $csvs = Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.csv
  $y = $csvs.Count
  Write-Host "Detected the following CSV files: ($y)"
  Write-Host " "$csvs.Name"`n"
  $outputfilename = "Final Registry Results"
  Write-Host Creating: $outputfilename
  $excelapp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
  $excelapp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = $csvs.Count
  $xlsx = $excelapp.Workbooks.Add()
  for($i=1;$i -le $y;$i++) {
    $worksheet = $xlsx.Worksheets.Item($i)
    $worksheet.Name = $csvs[$i-1].Name
    $file = (Import-Csv $csvs[$i-1].FullName)
    $file | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Clip
    $worksheet.Cells.Item(1).PasteSpecial()|out-null
    }

  $output = "F:\Registry_Export\Results\$DIR\$Date\Results.Xlsx"
  $xlsx.SaveAs($output)
  $excelapp.Quit()
}
```